# Can I substitute my VPN subscription with macOS's Private Relay?

Tags: network, security, vpn, privacy, icloud

**TL;DR:** Title.

---

I see that macOS's Private Relay essentially relays the internet traffic from my iMac to an internet endpoint (or rather an internet traffic light) in a way that neither Apple nor the visited website fully knows where the traffic originated from/is going to.

> When browsing with Safari, Private Relay ensures all traffic leaving a
> user’s device is encrypted, so no one between the user and the website
> they are visiting can access and read it, not even Apple or the user’s
> network provider. All the user’s requests are then sent through two
> separate internet relays. The first assigns the user an anonymous IP
> address that maps to their region but not their actual location. The
> second decrypts the web address they want to visit and forwards them
> to their destination. This separation of information protects the
> user’s privacy because no single entity can identify who a user is and
> which sites they visit.

---

So, is it time to stop paying for VPN?

The specific cases I use VPN for are:

1. Unlocking geolocation specific content;
2. Unlocking lower prices for services available in other countries;
3. Preventing data hoarders from knowing my actual location when surfing; and
4. Downloading torrents.

Comment: By that logic, you should use Tor.

Comment: @MarcWilson: Tor is definitely the safest option, which comes at a loss of internet speed. The goal is not to have a FBI-proof solution, rather a internet-advertising-industry proof solution. You know… Zuckerberg-proof… something like that.

Comment: VPN is a technology that provides a secure channel between two points which can be used in different scenarios for different purposes. You should specify what purpose you use VPN for.

Comment: @not2savvy: Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it will depend on the actual use case, the general answer is that *Private Relay is **not** a true substitute for VPN.*

---

While similar in idea, the specific cases where Private Relay and VPN differ are:

1. **Private Relay only works on Safari:** In a typical Apple fashion, you do not get the benefits of Private Relay if you use anything other than Safari. I verified it by opening an IP tracing website to find what my IP was being seen by it. Got different results on Safari and Firefox. Firefox exposed my actual IP; Safari didn't.
2. **You cannot change countries, using Private Relay.** Private Relay has only two options as of today:

   1. **General Location**, close to your actual location. So if you are in zipcode 12345, it will relay you to an endpoint close to that zip code. This enables that you get location-specific suggestions if you prefer while masking your true location.
   2. **Country and Time Zone.** ..which is even more general than 'General Location' and typically shows you close to a metro city in your time zone, in your country.

   As a result, if you are in the US, for example, you cannot change your country to Canada to access content that's available in Canada but not in the US.
3. **Private Relay may not be available in your country.** And as a result, VPN may be your only solution.

Comment: Also: “It’s easily identifiable as a “proxy server,” which many large networks like those at schools or businesses will not work with. Most good VPNs disguise themselves to look like regular non-proxy traffic.” - [macworld](https://www.macworld.com/article/348965/icloud-plus-private-relay-safari-vpn-ip-address-encryption-privacy.html)